# Bundling functions into classes vs functions as they are. Which option is more memory efficient?

Tags: python

Let's say I have 10 really random functions in a python file. I could keep them like that, or I could bundle them into a class.

Just for example:

```
def one:
   pass

def two:
   pass

#more 8 functions
```

If I wanted to bundle them into a class would it be more efficient or it doesn't make a difference?

```
class R:
   def one:
      pass

   #more 9 functions
```

So, which option is memory wise better?

Comment: Putting memory aside, why would you want to put them in a class just because? Classes have specific purposes and shouldn't be forced to use... If your functions don't ***need*** to be in a class (i.e. use some invariant state of an encapsulating object), I don't see any reason to put them inside one

Comment: Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202818/classes-vs-functions