# How is a class(object) different from a function

Tags: python, function, class, oop

So I understand that classes are basically blueprints for when you are coding, but the thing I don't understand is the difference they have from functions. Since for both of them you can assign variables and use different variables inside of them. And in order for both of them to work you have to use exampleclass() or examplefunction() for it to execute. Also as well you can execute a function inside a function or define a function within a functions and with a class you can execute or define a class inside a class.

example class:

```
class bank(object):
    def __init__(self, acc_num, acc_name, acc_DOB):
        self.acc_num = acc_num
        self.acc_name = acc_name
        self.acc_DOB = acc_DOB
```

or
example function:

```
def bank(num, name, DOB):
    acc_num = num
    acc_name = name
    acc_DOB = DOB
```

*The two example I have given may not be perfectly correct but I was doing off the top of my head.

The two examples I have given look exactly the same but and look like they do the same thing so what is the difference.

Comment: What do you think `b` would be after running `b = bank(1, 'bob', '1980-05-04')` with the class, or with the function? Can you do *anything* useful with the function?

Comment: (Also, `__init___` has too many underscores.)

Comment: Its just an example, its not an actual piece of code I'm just confused in why you would use a class and not just a function, @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: Don't they basically do the same thing @user2357112supportsMonica, just that with a function it would take more code and be longer to express the same thing as with the class. Since with the function you can retrieve data from outside the function to use inside it like with the DOB and name and acc num.

Comment: you will find a good answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202818/classes-vs-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions do specific things, classes are specific things.

Classes are a blueprint, like you said. A class can have methods inside of them, and in your example, you are showing the constructor in action. That method, when executed, creates a new object using that blueprint. Compared to the function you listed in your example, which creates local variables and sets them equal to the passed in parameters. Also, you can't "execute" a class. You can only call methods in it. Ex) class.method() compared to function().

[Classes vs. Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202818/classes-vs-functions)

Comment: Alright that is really helpful and I think that answers my question.